# how to integrate google deep linking?

Tags: unity-game-engine, deep-linking

I would like to integrate google deep linking into my unity3D game app.
Did anyone ever do this? Is this possible?

[Deep Linking Google](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fapp-indexing%2Fwebmasters%2Fapp&ei=CkDSVNSQAuf8ywOawoCADQ&usg=AFQjCNES0abhveY8OFgWpOY6xBdlVvggTA&sig2=NMdELvbCsb47sI1pm7IVmA)

Thanks.